# Can we list installed packages from a java 7 program?

Tags: package-management, java

is it possible to list all installed (official) packages from a Java 7 program ?
If so, how could I do it ?

Is looking at /usr/bin enough or may I miss some packages ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found

```
String [] extCmdArgs = new String[]{"dpkg-query", "-W", "-f=${Package} ${Version}\n"};
Process fetchInstalledPackagesProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(extCmdArgs);
BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fetchInstalledPackagesProcess.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while(true){
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
                System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        reader.close();
    }
```